# Cocos2d: is there a way to schedule the same selector for n times?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scheduler

My current solution to schedule the same selector on an object for n times is via creating an array of instances of a "messanger" class where as property I have calltime and type of the selector I want to call plus the object reference that should call the selector.

I then check against this array in the update method of the parent node class where I added all those objects.

Is there any way to do this via the schedule method?

The shared director doesn't give me any method that helps. I am fairly happy with my solution but not quiet sure if it is the best one.

EDIT: I tried the answer suggested and unfortunately did not work.

Here is the code:

```
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:1.0f];
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:3.0f];
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:5.0f];
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:7.0f];
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:9.0f];
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:12.0f];
     ....
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:152.0f];
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:177.0f];
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:199.0f];
    [f schedule:@selector(activateForShort) interval:0 repeat:0 delay:212.0f];
```

f is an object and it calls the selector "activateForShort" only once.

I tried modifying the interval and repeat value to 1 but did not work.

**What I want to achieve is to call it at a specific time (e.g. 1.0f, 212.0f).**

Any suggestion will be wellcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested sadly didn't work. See edit.

I created a specific action class and created an NSMutableArray filled of instances of this class, and in the update method of the class wherever I needed those actions to be scheduled I do:

```
-(void ) update:(ccTime) delta
{
timeElapsed+=delta;

for(int i=lastButtonCallIndex; i<[callsSchedulers count]; i++ )
{
    Call * buttonCall = [callsSchedulers objectAtIndex:i];
    if (buttonCall.callingTime<timeElapsed)
    {
        if(buttonCall.called==FALSE)
        {
            [buttonCall call]; //Where the call method has a reference to the button object I wanted to activate - a Call object is initialized with this reference.
            lastButtonCallIndex++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cocos2d 2.0 you can use the [schedule:interval:repeat:delay](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_node.html#ae12c910d6f81e4734aa575d70b3d4d45) method.

The repeat parameter is how many times the selector runs again after the initial run. Ie if repeat is 10 the selector will run 11 times.

The delay parameter determines the initial delay, so you can have it wait longer or shorter before the first time the selector runs.

Comment: Sorry for unaccepting but I tried and did not work.. I edited the question with the explanation.. will accept again if I did something wrong :)